# How to chain Map and forEach in lodash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, lodash, underscore.js

I'm trying to create an array of payloads using map and forEach on two different data sources. The payloads array should look like this:

```
const payloads = [{
  accountId: 1,
  tagId: 'tag1',
  notes: 'random note'
}, 
{
  accountId: 1,
  tagId: 'tag2',
  notes: 'random note'
}, 
{
  accountId: 1,
  tagId: 'tag3',
  notes: 'random note'
},
{
  accountId: 2,
  tagId: 'tag1',
  notes: 'random note'
},
...]
```

I have the following variables:

```
const ids = [1, 2, 3]
const tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
const notes = 'random note'
```

I'd like to create an array of payloads using this data so that each id has a separate payload with a each note.

I've tried doing the following with lodash map and forEach:

```
import { forEach, map } from 'lodash';

  const payloads = map(ids, id => forEach(tags, tag => {
    return ({
    accountId: id,
    tagId: tag,
    notes: note
  }
  )}));
```

This is just returning an array of tags. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, but I don't think I understand chaining correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You don't need the whole lodash library just for map and foreach functions. You can use built-in Array.prototype.forEach and Array.prototype.map instead.

Comment: Related: [Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12303989)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lodash's `forEach` always returns the input array as it is. So for each `map` operation, you're conceptually returning `tags` array without any transformations. The thing you need is another map operator as answered by Henry. But still a nested `map` would cause nested arrays as well. So instead of your required result, the result would be like

```
[
    [ {Object}, {Object}, {Object} ],
    [ {Object}, {Object}, {Object} ],
    [ {Object}, {Object}, {Object} ]
]
```

To deal with the nesting, you need to use `Array.prototype.flat` on the transformed result.

So your code would look like

```js
const ids = [1, 2, 3]
const tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
const notes = 'random note'
const payloads = _.map(ids, id => _.map(tags, tag => {
        return ({
        accountId: id,
        tagId: tag,
        notes: notes
      })})).flat();
console.log(payloads);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I tried doing that, but the `accountId` key is an array of ALL the ids for some reason

Comment: @Jav then there must be something else. I've added a runnable form of code snippet. Please try that out. It clearly shows the output that you want.

Comment: It was an error with my input, thanks a lot for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `map` both times rather than `forEach`:

```js
const ids = [1, 2, 3]
const tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
const note = 'random note'

const results = _.flatten(_.map(ids, id => _.map(tags, tag => ({
  accountId: id,
  tagId: tag,
  notes: note
}))));

console.log(results)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

Plain JavaScript:

```js
const ids = [1, 2, 3]
const tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
const note = 'random note'

const results = ids.map(id => tags.map(tag => ({
    accountId: id,
    tagId: tag,
    notes: note
}))).flat();

console.log(results)
```